# Limit of fraction with epsilon proof

Tags: limits

> Let $g(n)=\frac{2n^2-n-1}{n^2+3n+2}$  for $n\in R_+\cup \left \{ 0 \right \}$.
>
> Show that $g(n)\rightarrow 2$ for $n \rightarrow \infty $.

I have tried so far

$$\left |\frac{2n^2-n-1}{n^2+3n+2}-2  \right |=\left | \frac{-7n-5}{(n+1)(n+2)} \right |=\frac{7n+5}{(n+1)(n+2)}<\varepsilon $$

I think that I have to make some boundaries, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: It's not a good notation to write $n$ for an element of $\mathbb R^+$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

When $x>1$,
$$\frac{7x+5}{(x+1)(x+2)}\leq \frac{7x+5}{x^2}\leq \frac{12}{x}.$$

Let $\varepsilon>0$. If you take $M=\max\{\frac{12}{\varepsilon},1\}$, you'll get the result (i.e. that $|g(x)-2|<\varepsilon$ when $x>M$.)

Comment: I can't understand the last inequality.  $\frac{7x+5}{x^2}\leq \frac{12}{x}$. I know that  $\frac{7x+5}{x^2}\leq \frac{7x+5}{x}=7+\frac{5}{x}$

Comment: When $x\geq 1$, you have that $\frac{1}{x^2}\leq \frac{1}{x}$. @JakobHenriksen

Comment: Sure, but how is $7x+5 \leq 12$ for all $x>1$?

Comment: $$\frac{7x+5}{x^2}=\frac{7}{x}+\frac{5}{x^2},$$ do you see now ? @JakobHenriksen

Comment: That, or $7x+5\leqslant7x+5x=12x$.

Comment: I see! Alternative could I use  $\frac{7x+5}{x}=7+\frac{5}{x}<\epsilon$ and calculate a value for $\epsilon$?

Comment: @JakobHenriksen: This inequality won't allowed you to conclude since it's limit is $7$ and not $0$ !